Why Cmake does not accept my build type command but taking with cli?
I am using fecth_content in my CMake something like:
FetchContent_Declare(
    Logger
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/fehimkus/MessageLogger.git
    GIT_TAG main
)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(Logger)

It is pretty straightforward. Right? But i want to give some arguments the Logger's Cmake, like build on release mode. For that I am writing on the main Cmake something like that;
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)

But submodule (fetch_content stuff) does not take this and is built with DEBUG mode.
Then I wrote with cli that;
mkdir -p build && cmake -B build -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DBUILD_TESTS=OFF

Surprisingly it is worked! I did not understand why. If anyone can help me about this issue I will be very appreciated.
Solution EDIT: @Tsyvarev was right. I should wrote it frstly

Where in your code you set CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE? Before FetchContent_MakeAvailable or after it?

after. but as i know cmake is a imperative language? does it matter where i wrote it?

No, CMake is a sequential configuration language: lines in CMakeLists.txt are executed one by one. Some commands (like add_executable) have deferred effects of declaring things for a build time (e.g. create rules which will compile and link the executable). Effects for some other commands (e.g. target_link_libraries) are processed at the very end of the configuration. But when it is concerned about variables, their processing is fully sequential.

Note also, that some variables are treated as "global" in CMake. E.g. CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE variable is expected be set somewhere at the beginning of the project and be never changed. Changing this variable in the middle of the project could result in weird problems. So, you shouldn't treat CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE variable as "an argument" for a subproject. You are better to thing about this variable as a global, which should be set somewhere at the beginning of your project and which affects all subprojects too.
